# Create txt file outside website root folder with StreamWriter

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, streamwriter

Is it possible for a web application to write a text file outsite the root folder (like, C:\test.txt) using the `StreamWriter`? I wasn't able to make it work even with full permissions.

```
        string vRegistro = "Some test";
        StreamWriter tex = new StreamWriter(@"\\ICOM\public.txt", true, Encoding.UTF8);

        tex.WriteLine(vRegistro);
        tex.Close();
```

Comment: And `@"C:\ICOM\public.txt"` ?

Comment: The code you have, isn't even a valid attempt, to write it OUTSIDE of the root directory.   Using `\\` would indicate `Root\\...` which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\\ICOM\public.txt` will be interpreted as a UNC path, since is starts with a double backslash.

It is not a valic UNC at that.

Removing a backslash from the start will result in a file called `public.txt` being written to the ICOM folder of your application environment's root directory.